# Why is Node.js's bytecode output so large?

Tags: node.js, v8

Running `node --print-bytecode` on a file containing code as minimal as just `void 0;` produces a file the size of which is 2.3 MB. Looking through it, I thought it was including assembly code generated by JIT compilation, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Still, that doesn't explain why it's big. Compare it to the output of `javap` which, even though it's for a different language, is much smaller and much more readable.

Comment: It's verbose, hence its output is bigger. I think that explains why its bigger. If you want to know why it's so verbose you should ask the core developers.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone What is it even saying though?

Answer (score 3):

> I thought it was including assembly code generated by JIT compilation, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Correct, bytecode is not assembly code. Assembly code will be generated later, for functions that run hot enough that V8 decides optimizing them is likely worth the time investment.

> Why is Node.js's bytecode output so large? [...] on a file containing code as minimal as just `void 0;`

A lot of Node itself is written in JavaScript, and all of that gets compiled to bytecode before being executed. So even if you run Node on an empty file, you'll see quite a bit of bytecode.

> What is it even saying though?

It's saying the same as the JavaScript code it was generated from. What exactly the individual bytecode instructions do and how to read them is an internal implementation detail of V8 and can change at any time. As a user of Node (or V8), you're not supposed to have a reason to care; and in particular you shouldn't assume that the bytecode format is stable over time/versions. Printing it at all is meant for debugging engine-internal issues.